# Writing Output to Middle of File

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am currently working on a script that loops through an input file, the input file has a format similar to an /etc/hosts file in Linux. For example, the input file would look something like this:

```
192.168.1.21     host1
192.168.1.17     host5
192.168.1.168    host9
192.168.1.3      host3
192.168.1.37     host4
```

The data from the input file would need to be added to another file (an already existing hosts file) but it would need to be sorted in alphabetical order.

The following code snippet shows how I coded my script.

```
#Assign parameters to variables
inputFile=$1
hostsFile=$2

while read line
do

#Extract data from input file
ipAddress=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'` 
hostName=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`

    #Loop to add host to hostname file, maintaining alphabetical order
    while read line
    do
        addHost=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
        if [[ $profileEntry < $deviceName ]]; then
            #Add device in sorted alphabetical order 
            echo $ipAddress "\t" $hostName >> $hostsFile
            break;
        fi
    done < $hostsFile

done < $inputFile
```

I am doing the string comparison but when I write to the file using the >> or > operators the output will be append to the end of the file. Is there any Linux ksh construct or other method that can be used in shell scripts that will allow me to insert lines of text in alphabetical order, as opposed to appending text to the end of a file.

Comment: The operating system itself doesn't have an insert operation. You very literally can't insert data in the middle of a file without rewriting everything after it in *any* language, even in C. (There are exceptions, but they require a filesystem with special support, the content you want to insert to be an exact multiple of the block size and on a block boundary).

Comment: BTW, `while read -r ipAddress hostName` will let you avoid the unnecessary `awk`. And never `echo $line` without quoting `"$line"` -- otherwise, if `line=*` you get a list of filenames on output, tabs get replaced with spaces, and various other munging happens.

Comment: Similarly, `printf '%s\t%s\n' "$ipAddress" "$hostName"` is a more reliable way to do the output (not depending on an `echo` with XSI extensions)

Comment: Thanks for the tips on cleaning up my script. I've been looking at alternative solutions online. Though its not exactly a native shell feature, I think maybe using sed can help me. If there is a way I can use sed to sort the lines of text and rewrite the file then that would work good for me. Otherwise I can just append the strings and use the sort command to sort the file.

Comment: `sed -i` literally does the same thing my answer does, creating a temporary file and renaming it. That said, it does it while being less portable (since the `-i` option has incompatible behavior between GNU and BSD systems).

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I'm pretty new to shell scripting but with your explanations I now have a firm grasp of this concept. You can only rewrite or append to a file using Linux shell scripting. I rewrote my script by just appending the lines of input to my hosts file. After my loop exits, I run a sort command, as follows: sort -u -k 2 -o $hostsFile $hostsFile. This has the effect of sorting the file by the second column (the hostname column) and I added the -u flag to remove duplicates. Thanks again for your help. I think you posted a similar solution below.

Comment: Using the same file for input and output isn't necessarily safe, unless the documentation for `sort -o` specifies that it doesn't open the output file until after it's consumed all input (which usually isn't the case, since doing that means a command needs to buffer output in memory or a temporary file). You can get into a race condition where you delete content that hasn't been read yet, and thus truncate content early.

Comment: ...thinking about it, for `sort` specifically, that might possibly be fine, since except in the case of merge sorts (where inputs' ordering is guaranteed), it can't be certain it's seen the first line of output until all input has been consumed. It's still not necessarily a good habit to be in.

Comment: @Eddie Beware with `sort -u -k2`.  The option `-u` will only look at the fields specified with `-k`.  It's perfectly acceptable to have two ip addresses for a single host.  You may have a policy to enforce one unique address, but `sort` would not know your policy, and you get unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible: The OS itself has no way to do insertions (as opposed to replacements) of content in the middle of a file. Other than when `O_APPEND` is in effect, `write()` calls overwrite and replace any content immediately after the current position of the file pointer.

Write a new file from scratch, and rename it over the original you're trying to replace; this has the benefit of being an atomic operation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

inputFile=$1
hostsFile=$2
tempFile=$(mktemp "${hostsFile}.XXXXXX")

if sort -u -- "$inputFile" "$hostsFile" >"$tempFile"; then
  mv -- "$tempFile" "$hostsFile" && exit
fi
rm -f -- "$tempFile"
```